# How to unit test a console program that reads input and writes to the console

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

Let's say I have a simple program like

```
using System;

public class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), int.Parse);
        Array.Sort(arr);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", arr));
    }
}
```

which I want to test in a separate project like

```
[TestMethod]
public void TwoNumbersDescendingAreSwapped()
{
     string input = "2 1";
     string expectedOutput = "1 2"; 
     // ... ???
     Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, actualOutput);
}
```

Is it possible to do that without actually using the .exe from Solution?

Comment: _"without actually using the .exe from Solution?"_ -- what does that mean? How are you going to test the code in the .exe without using the .exe in _some_ way? I can think of at least two ways to test the code, but both involve using the code. I don't know how you'd test the code without using it, so you need to be more specific and clear about what you mean. Noting, of course, that even if your question was understandable, it'd be too broad, as pretty much any "is it possible?" question is. You need to _try_ something, and ask questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Yes it is possible if you use TypeMock isolator or Microsoft Fakes. For Fakes if you have Enterprise edition of VS, happy to provide the solution

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Move the code that does all the work in `Main()` to its own class and method:

```
public static class InputConverter
{
    public static string ConvertInput(string input)
    {
        int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(input.Split(' '), int.Parse);
        Array.Sort(arr);
        return string.Join(" ", arr);        
    }
}
```

Your `Main()` then becomes:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    var output = InputConverter.ConvertInput(input);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

You can now test `ConvertInput()` without being dependent by the write and read functions of `Console`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TwoNumbersDescendingAreSwapped()
{
    // Arrange
    var input = "2 1";
    var expectedOutput = "1 2"; 
    // Act
    var actualOutput = InputConverter.ConvertInput(input);
    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, actualOutput);
}
```

As an aside: the way you are passing in your arguments seems as though you are guaranteeing that the input will always be what you expect it to be. What happens when the user passes in something totally different than string representations of integers? You need to validate the input in `InputConverter.ConvertInput()` and create appropriate courses of action based on that (throw an `Exception`, return `null`, depends on what you're after). You'll then have to unit test those scenarios as well to make sure `ConvertInput()` performs as expected for all cases.

Comment: Ha. You beat me to this. Nice answer.

Comment: @JordanS.Jones happens to me more often than not! :) Thanks.

Comment: I tried this approach but the problem I'm facing is that the console window just doesn't show up at all. So, I I can't input anything...

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper this example was for a console app - as for the unit test, there's no `Console` involved (the point of separating it out into `InputConverter`)

Comment: Forehead slapper of the century. Thanks for pointing out the obvious :)

Comment: @Yablargo how many times I had to be pointed out the obvious :) Glad I could help.